# How to destroy an artifact?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

On level 1 Inconsequentia gave me a request to defeat a regiment, claim an artifact and destroy it at the monolith. I defeated the regiment, got the artifact and now am standing next to a monolith on the next level. How do I now destroy the artifact? I can neither equip it nor drop it on the monolith.

Comment: If my memory serves me right, clicking on the artifact in your inventory to select it, then clicking on the monolith on the map (dropping it on the monolith) should destroy the artifact. The monolith must be on the same level as the artifact.

Comment: After searching through level 1 again I found a monolith there, not sure if it spawned later or if I had overlooked it the first time.

Comment: @erik Monolits are created at map generation, they do not spawn later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: The Quest]

First, you've got the quest.  This is a *slightly* different version of the quest - two of the steps are flipped.  In this quest I start with the artifact, find the shrine, use the artifact, and then defeat the bad guys.

[image: The Artifact]

In this quest, the artifact has the shape of a brain.  There are many other shapes.  When you have to find an artifact on the map, if you've been to that spot it has a red crosshair.

[image: The mini map]

Next, I've got to find the altar.  This one is the eyeball shrine, and it shows up on the minimal as a little eyeball thing.  There is only and always one shrine per level.  Note that the quest item must be used on the ***same*** level as the quest was given (and completed) on (this is likely your issue).

[image: The Shrine]

Here, picked up the item from my inventory and am standing next to the shrine.  Dropping it on the shrine will then...

[image: The 93 regiment]

summon the regiment that I have to beat.

[image: The Minimap]

Note on the minimap, the "beat these monsters" quest monsters show up as red.